# No Resource found that matches @integer/google_play_service_version

Tags: android

I have imported **google-play-services_lib** to my project but getting error @integer/google_play_services_version in AndroidManifest.xml

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').AndroidManifest.xml
```

This is the code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

I have added its [Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zJbR.png) also. Yet it cannot be resolved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zJbR.png

I am new to android and I have checked most of the possible solutions but didn't work for me.

Comment: You are using gradle right? what do you mean google-play-serices_lib?

Comment: Google Play Service Library. I have added it in properties->Is Library

Comment: I am still confused, can you upload our build.gradle file?

Comment: I am using eclipse and cannot find gradle file. Can you please tell me?

Comment: Sorry can't help you. Eclipse is unsupported. You should really switch to Android Studio

Comment: Here is how to migrate: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

Comment: I am using android studio but given a project in eclipse

Comment: @KVC make sure meta-data tag is defined inside application tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that Eclipse is not encouraged by google. But they still have setup guide at this official document https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup explains how to setup google play for eclipse. Basically:

> Copy the library project at
> /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/
> to the location where you maintain your Android app projects.
>
> Import
> the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click File > Import,
> select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to
> the copy of the library project to import it.
>
> In your app project,
> reference Google Play services library project. See Referencing a
> Library Project for Eclipse for more information on how to do this.